# How to transfer multiple columns into numeric & find correlation coefficients

Tags: r, loops, iteration, correlation

I have a dataset "res.sav" that I read in via haven. It contains 20 columns, called "Genes1_Acc4", "Genes2_Acc4" etc. I am trying to find a correlation coefficient between those and another column called "Condition". I want to separately list all coefficients.

I created two functions, cor.condition.cols and cor.func to do that. The first iterates through the filenames and works just fine. The second was supposed to give me my correlations which didn't work at all. I also created a new "cor.condition.Genes" which I would like to fill with the correlations, ideally as a matrix or dataframe.

I have tried to iterate through the columns with two functions. However, when I try to pass it, I get the error: "NAs introduced by conversion". This wouldn't be the end of the world (I tried also suppressWarning()). But the bigger problem I have that it seems like my function does not convert said columns into the numeric type I need for my cor() function. I receive the "y must be numeric" error when trying to run the cor() function. I tried to put several arguments within and without '' or "" without success.

When I ran str(cor.condition.cols) I only receive character strings, which makes me think that my function somehow messes up with the as.numeric function. Any suggestions of how else I could iter through these columns and transfer them?

Thanks guys :)

```
cor.condition.cols <- lapply(1:20, function(x){paste0("res$Genes", x, "_Acc4")})

#save acc_4 columns as numeric columns and calculate correlations
res <- (as.numeric("cor.condition.cols"))
cor.func <- function(x){
  cor(res$Condition, x, use="complete.obs", method="pearson")
}

cor.condition.Genes <- cor.func(cor.condition.cols)
```

Comment: Please edit your question: please put the result from `dput(head(yourDataframe))` in your question.

Comment: There are a number of discrepancies here. I recommend that you walk through each line of your code and check the output so you understand what's going on. `cor.condition.cols` is a variable and not a function, and `cor.condition.cols <- lapply(…)`  creasts a list of charactor vectors. `res <- (as.numeric("cor.condition.cols"))` tries to *convert the string `"cor.condition.cols"`* to numeric, which isn't possible, so an `NA` is returned with a warning. The upshot is that `cor(…)` tries to find the correlation between a list of character vectors and a single `NA`.

Comment: What kind of output do you expect? **I want to separately list all coefficients.**

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
cor.condition.cols <- paste0("Genes", 1:20, "_Acc4")
res2 <- as.numeric(as.matrix(res[cor.condition.cols]))
cor.condition.Genes <- cor(res2, res$Condition, use="complete.obs", method="pearson")
```

eventually the short variant:

```
cor.condition.cols <- paste0("Genes", 1:20, "_Acc4")
cor.condition.Genes <- cor(res[cor.condition.cols], res$Condition, use="complete.obs")
```

Here is an example with other data:

```
cor(iris[-(4:5)], iris[[4]])
```